# Parse - How do I query a Class and include another that points to it?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have two classes - _User and Car.  A _User will have a low/limited number of Cars that they own.  Each Car has only ONE owner and thus an "owner" column that is a  to the _User.  When I got to the user's page, I want to see their _User info and all of their Cars.  I would like to make one call, in Cloud Code if necessary.

Here is where I get confused.  There are 3 ways I could do this -

1. In _User have a relationship column called "cars" that points to each individual Car.  If so, how come I can't use the "include(cars)" function on a relation to include the Cars' data in my query?!!
   **_User.cars = relationship, Car.owner = _User(pointer)**
2. Query the _User, and then query all Cars with (owner == _User.objectId) separately.  This is two queries though.
   **_User.cars = null, Car.owner = _User(pointer)**
3. In _User have a array of pointers column called "cars".  Manually inject pointers to cars upon car creation.  When querying the user I would use "include(cars)".
   **_User.cars = [Car(pointer)], Car.owner = _User(pointer)**

What is your recommended way to do this and why? Which one is the fastest?  The documentation just leaves me further confused.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the 3rd option, and yes, you can ask to include an array. You even don't need to "manually inject" the pointers, you just need to add the objects into the array and they'll automatically be converted into pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right ideas.  Just to clarify them a bit:

1. A relation.  User can have a relation column called cars.  To get from user to car, there's a user query and then second query like `user.relation("cars").query`, on which you would `.find()`.
2. What you might call a belongs_to pointer in Car.  To get from user to car you'd have a query to get your `user` and you create a carQuery like `carQuery.equalTo("user", user)`
3. An array of pointers.  For small-sized collections, this is superior to the relation, because you can aggressively load cars when querying user by saying `include("cars")` on a user query.  Not sure if there's a second query under the covers - probably not if parse (mongo) is storing these as embedded.

But I wouldn't get too tied up over one or two queries.  Using the promise forms of `find()` will keep your code nice and tidy.  There probably is a small speed advantage to the array technique, which is good while the collection size is small (<100 is my rule of thumb).

It's easy to google (or I'll add here if you have a specific question) code examples for maintaining the relations and for getting from user->car or from car->user for each approach.

Comment: And that's why he has 30k+ rep points. While I only gave you my suggestion, he explained how he (and I) choose between them. I'll work my way to get there. Upvoted =]